# Javascript vs C++, same code, different result, why is that?

Tags: javascript, c++

I'm doing a code challenge and I found some strange stuff going on with my code, so I ran it with C++

```
function sumPrimes (num)
{
    var sum=0;
    for(var i=2; i<num; i++)
    {
        if(primeNumber(i)===true)
            sum+=i;
    }
    return sum;
}


function primeNumber (i)
{
    if(i==2 || i==3 || i==5 || i==7)
        return true;
    if(i%2!=0 && i%3!=0 && i%5!=0 && i%7!=0)
        return true;
}

sumPrimes(977);
```

which gives me result of 107812, but when I do the same with C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool primeNumber(int);
int sumPrimes(int);
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "n: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Sum : " << sumPrimes(n) << endl;
    system("PAUSE>=0");
}
int sumPrimes(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (primeNumber(i) == true)
            sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
bool primeNumber(int i)
{
    if (i == 2 || i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 7)
        return true;
    if (i % 2 != 0 && i % 3 != 0 && i % 5 != 0 && i % 7 != 0)
        return true;
}
```

the result is 108583.

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: When does `primeNumber` return false? Maybe a hint.

Comment: But you _are_ aware, that the prime test you use declares many numbers as prime which are not, the first being 121?

Comment: C++ behavior when execution reaches the end of a non-void function without explicitly returning a value is undefined.

Comment: @AndrewMedico ... and JavaScript will return `undefined`.

Comment: If this was the correct implementation of `isPrimeNumber` we would have a big problem with todays encryption...

Comment: @migg OP is clearly trying to learn. No need to be saucy.

Comment: You need to test your algorithm.  Here are some numbers 121 (11 * 11), (13 * 11), (13 * 13).

Comment: @erip Was not intended to be saucy.

Answer (score 6):

There are two major problems with both programs.

- ## You never explicitly return `false` if the conditions aren't met!

These programming languages can't read your mind, so they don't understand that if you don't return `true` if a condition is met, you also want to return `false` is the condition *isn't* met.

Your JS code returns `undefined` if something isn't returned upon execution of function.

Your C++ code actually invokes undefined behavior (UB) because execution reached the end of a non-void function without a return value.

Unfortunately neither of these guarantee a `false`. A simple (perhaps naive?) solution is to just plop a `return false;` right before the end curly.

- ## Your algorithm is incorrect!

Since you're trying to improve your skills, I'll leave this one as an exercise, but I would recommend thinking about the definition of a prime number a little more. :)

Comment: my algorithm works fine for about 100, but classic rookie mistake, someone will input 595295 and my algorithm won't work lol

but thanks men, didn't know that JS returns undefined..


and, what still bugs me, why the same algorithm, code, gives back different results :S

Comment: @code_newbie23 That's fine! If you have any more questions, feel free to add another question.

Comment: @code_newbie23 Because of the undefined behavior, _anything_ can be returned by the C++ code. Maybe something true, maybe something false. If you add `return false;` to the end of both, they should return the same (incorrect) thing.

Comment: @code_newbie23 See here: [C++](http://ideone.com/ZVQdAN) vs. [JS](http://ideone.com/f4mFjI)